# Excel - Pulling dates and null values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to pull dates from one sheet to another sheet, and I'd like them to automatically propagate. I need a blank (or a space!) when pulling from a null cell, otherwise, I'd like the date to show. If I use a ='Sheet1"&"", I get my nulls quite nicely, but dates are no longer numbers, and won't format properly. If I don't, I get 0's when I'd like a null.

I could put a space into every spot where I expect a date in the future, but I'm slightly concerned about other users not realizing there's a space to remove, and causing problems then. Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1="","",TEXT(Sheet1!A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

and copy down.

[image]